# Share library among multiple application deployed in Mule esb

Tags: java, mule, mule-component

I have  multiple application deployed in mule esb. All these application have same set of jars so I am trying to create a shared library . If I place all the jars in %mule_home%/lib/user then it works fine, but I am trying to put these jars into my custom folders.for example %mule_home%/lib/user/hibernate then I am not able to deploy my applications.

Comment: Are you using maven ?

Comment: No, i am not using Maven.

Comment: Hi, ok let's say that if you where using maven you didn't had this issue, as everything was packaged with your deploy without issues. Anyway if this is still the way you want to go it's normal that he will not pick up on subfloder, they are not on the path.
The only way you have is to create an unique jar containing all your jars and that put it in lib/users. But again I do recommend you to use maven for painless (more or less) dependency management.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion . Is there any way I can change in the configuration so it picks up jars from specific folder inside lib/users.

Comment: Have a look at the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok let's say that if you where using maven you didn't had this issue, as everything was packaged with your deploy without issues.

Anyway if this is still the way you want to go it's normal that he will not pick up on subfloder, they are not on the path.

One way you have is to create an unique jar containing all your jars and that put it in lib/users.

There is probally also another way, even if I didn't tested it and I would also not encourage.
You could go play with the mule wrapper.conf and add folders to the classpath, as you can see around the line [118 of the file](https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/91f36d45a0b0744cd36f2c3037618aa7f5a655b1/distributions/standalone/src/main/resources/conf/wrapper.conf#L118):

But again I do recommend you to use maven for painless (more or less) dependency management.

Answer (score 0):

Mule allows libraries seperation by using the domains. The application domain can be configured in `mule-deploy.properties`. For example:

```
domain=hibernate-apps
```

Place all your libs the needed libs into the domain folder. Has been tested with Mule 3.8.5.